# Using Stored Procedure in Classical ASP .. execute and get results

Tags: sql, asp-classic, ado

I tried to solve this all day long but it doesn't seem to work for me. I would like to execute a command and get the result back to a recordset.

The problem is one of two things: either I'm getting an empty response or there is a problem with my code. I know for sure that this command should fetch few lines from the DB. I added `response.write` inside the loop, but they are never printed.

Here is the code:

```vbs
Set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.open "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;DATA SOURCE=X;DATABASE=Y;UID=Z;PWD=W;"
Set objCommandSec = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
With objCommandSec
    Set .ActiveConnection = Conn
    .CommandType = 4
    .CommandText = "usp_Targets_DataEntry_Display"
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@userinumber ", 200, 1, 10, inumber)
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@group ", 200, 1, 50, "ISM")
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@groupvalue", 200, 1, 50, ismID)
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@targettypeparam ", 200, 1, 50, targetType)
End With 
    
set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet") 
rs = objCommandSec.Execute

while not rs.eof
    response.write (1)
    response.write (rs("1_Q1"))
    rs.MoveNext
wend
response.write (2)
```

**EDITED**
After revising the code, following @Joel Coehoorn answer, the solution is:

```vb
set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet") 
rs.oppen objCommandSec
```

instead of...

```vbs
set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet") 
rs = objCommandSec.Execute
```

Comment: +1 just for using parameterized queries in old asp.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Thank you, I tried to do it the best way. so do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looked at this for a few minutes, and it's been a *long* time since I've worked with classic asp, but I did see three things to look at:

1. Do you need to `Open` the connection before calling `objCommandSec.Execute`?
2. Can you try writing out a string literal inside the loop, that does not depend at all on the recordset... only that you are in fact looping through the code, so see if records are coming back to the recordset.
3. Have you checked the html source, to see if perhaps malformed html is hiding your results? I remember this happening a few times with tables in classic asp loops, where data would be hidden somehow between two rows, or a closing table tag in the wrong place would end the table, and later rows would not be visible.

Answer (score 10):

Couple of tips after working with [asp-classic](/questions/tagged/asp-classic) for years

1. There is no need to create a `ADODB.Connection` you can pass a connection string direct to `.ActiveConnection` property of the `ADODB.Command` object. This has two benefits, you don't have instantiate and open another object and because the context is tied to the `ADODB.Command` it will be released with `Set objCommandSec = Nothing`.
2. A common reason for `.Execute` returning a closed recordset is due to `SET NOCOUNT ON` not being set in your SQL Stored Procedure, as an `INSERT` or `UPDATE` will generate a records affected count and closed recordset. Setting `SET NOCOUNT ON` will stop these outputs and only your expected recordset will be returned.
3. Using `ADODB.Recordset` to cycle through your data is overkill unless you need to move backwards and forwards through and support some of the more lesser used methods that are not needed for standard functions like displaying a recordset to screen. Instead try using an `Array`.

   ```vb
   Const adParamInput = 1
   Const adVarChar = 200
   Dim conn_string, row, rows, ary_data

   conn_string = "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;DATA SOURCE=X;DATABASE=Y;UID=Z;PWD=W;"

   Set objCommandSec = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
   With objCommandSec
     .ActiveConnection = conn_string
     .CommandType = 4
     .CommandText = "usp_Targets_DataEntry_Display"
     .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@userinumber", adVarChar, adParamInput, 10, inumber)
     .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@group", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, "ISM")
     .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@groupvalue", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, ismID)
     .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@targettypeparam", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, targetType)

     Set rs = .Execute()
     If Not rs.EOF Then ary_data = rs.GetRows()
     Call rs.Close()
     Set rs = Nothing
   End With
   Set objCommandSec = Nothing

   'Command and Recordset no longer needed as ary_data contains our data.
   If IsArray(ary_data) Then
     ' Iterate through array
     rows = UBound(ary_data, 2)
     For row = 0 to rows
       ' Return our row data
       ' Row N column 2 (index starts from 0)
       Call Response.Write(ary_data(1, row) & "")
     Next
   Else
     ' Nothing returned
     Call Response.Write("No data returned")
   End If
   ```

Comment: The 
SET NOCOUNT ON worked for me... Thanks

Comment: I was able to solve my problem from this example.

Answer (score 0):

Although this might not answer OPs question directly, it might help someone else looking for a solution.

recently I had a maintenance job that required me to modify something in a running ASP classic code (which I haven't write in ages). Procedure calls were written the same way as OP did and that wasn't how I did it in the past.

Here is the syntax I used in the past and I think it is a little more clean than other solutions provided here.

The following code shows how to read an output parameter, pass parameters to stored procedure, pass null value to parameter, read record count, and iterate in RecordSet.

```
dim conn, cmd, rs

set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=servername;Uid=username;Pwd=password;Database=dbname;"

set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
cmd.CommandText = "procedurename"
cmd.Parameters.Refresh
cmd.Parameters("@nullparam") = null
cmd.Parameters("@strparam") = "1"
cmd.Parameters("@numparam") = 100

set rs = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.RecordSet")
rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient ' to read recordcount'

rs.open cmd, , adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly

Response.Write "Return Value: " & cmd.Parameters("@RETURN_VALUE") & "<br />"
Response.Write "Record count: " & rs.RecordCount & "<br />"
while not rs.EOF 
    ' or do whatever you like with data'
    Response.Write rs("colname") & "<br>"
    rs.MoveNext
wend
```

Comment: Why is that cleaner? First off your using the `ADODB.Recordset` open which in itself is an overhead, you also open a separate `ADODB.Connection` which means you then have to close it yourself rather then letting the `ADODB.Command` handle it for you. The only real benefit I can see is the use of `cmd.Parameters.Refresh` which only works with certain providers but is my preferred method when using SQL Server.

Comment: Connection is a limited resource, and many hosts do not allow more than one connection per page instance to their sql server. Opening one connection makes it possible. Opening recordset is to get record count, if you don't need record count you can use execute instead. Closing connection is not necessary, as soon as page is rendered, IIS will drop the page and all its resources including connection. by being cleaner I was referring to `.Parameters.Append .CreateParameter` and the dot that refers to line above.

Comment: Flawed argument you're making too many assumptions about IIS garbage collection, you will never convince me that holding a connection open to a database for the life of a page is a good idea.

Comment: Also bear in mind that `.Refresh` brings with it the overhead of having to make a second round trip to the server to get the parameter definitions and isn't recommended in production environments for this very reason.