# Classic ASP(VB Script) array 0x800A0009 'Subscript out of range error'

Tags: arrays, vbscript, asp-classic

I am maintaining an legacy system.
I have never dealt with Classic ASP, and I have little programming knowledge.
You want to group values having a two-dimensional array and store them in different two-dimensional arrays.
I'm getting an array subscript error and I can't fix what the problem is.

Can someone help me?

== Result data ==

| idx | type | pos | name | url | height | rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9 | A | top | alex | /citmi | 201 | 15 |
| 8 | C | left | james | /oftim | 198 | 120 |
| 7 | A | bottom | colin | /stici | 170 | 232 |
| 6 | F | middle | rhys | /citmi | 183 | 181 |
| 5 | B | top | bruce | /oftim | 20 | 176 |

```vb
    strqry = "SELECT idx "
    strqry = strqry& ",type "
    strqry = strqry& ",pos "
    strqry = strqry& ",name "
    strqry = strqry& ",url "
    strqry = strqry& ",height "
    strqry = strqry& ",rank "
    strqry = strqry& "FROM [database].[dbo].[table] "
    strqry = strqry& "WHERE is_apply = 0 "

    dbopen()
    
    Set Rs = Dbcon.Execute(strqry)

Function AddItem(arr, val)
    ReDim Preserve arr(UBound(arr) + 1, 1) '<== Subscript out of range error
    arr(UBound(arr,1)) = val '<= Type error predicted
    AddItem = arr
End Function

Dim listA_1(0,6), listA_2(0,6), listB_1(0,6), listC_1(0,6)

    Do Until Rs.Eof
        ViewNum = CInt(Rs("rank"))
        If ((0 < ViewNum) AND (ViewNum < 80)) Then
            listA_1 = AddItem(listA_1, Rs)
        ElseIf ((80 <= ViewNum) AND (ViewNum < 100)) Then
            listA_2 = AddItem(listA_2, Rs)
        ElseIf ((180 <= ViewNum) AND (ViewNum < 200)) Then
            listB_1 = AddItem(listB_1, Rs)
        ElseIf ((280 <= ViewNum) AND (ViewNum < 300)) Then
            listC_1 = AddItem(listC_1, Rs)
        End If
        Rs.MoveNext
    Loop
```

Comment: You're returning an `ADODB.Recordset` so why not just use [`rs.GetRows()` to return a 2-Dimensional Array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22305896/692942)?

Comment: From the [official documentation for `ReDim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/c850dt17(v=vs.84)) - "If you use the `Preserve` keyword, **you can resize only the last array dimension**, and you can't change the number of dimensions at all. For example, if your array has only one dimension, you can resize that dimension because it is the last and only dimension. However, if your array has two or more dimensions, you can change the size of only the last dimension and still preserve the contents of the array.".

Comment: @user692942 
I'm new to Classic ASP, and I don't know why I didn't use GetRows() because I was maintaining it according to the rules and framework made by my predecessor.
Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @user692942
I understand enough. Thanks for your detailed explanation.