# ASP Classic Getting and Setting the Conn to another Conn object

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic

I am using this way to connect and use the Conn object for connections

```
 <!-- #include file="dataconnections.asp" -->
```

In one of my ASP pages, I have a VBScript Onclick event that needs me to execute a stored procedure and pass the variables in the textboxes.

Right now, the Connection String is hardcoded in the ASP File itself and is not using the Conn object from the include file. Is there any proper way to execute the SP without using a new Conn, or how can I pass the current Conn from the include file to the one being used in the VBScript Onclick event?

Comment: Presumably your include file has a connection object defined? That should be visible from the server side code in your asp file.

Comment: VBScript Onclick event/ VBScript functions doesnt recognize preprocessed asp codes, or am I missing something.

Comment: Inside your click event handle you need to execute server side code. <% Put your server code inside here %>

Comment: You mean the connection string? I wanted to do something like this Set NewConn = <%=IncludeConn%>

Comment: What's the code inside of the include file look like?

Comment: You're not missing something @SeanLange is talking utter rot. This is Classic ASP not ASP.Net preprocessing isn't supported.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your include `dataconnections.asp` contains (*would have been nice if you had posted the source code in your question*) but a stored procedure is best run using the `ADODB.Command` object which exposes the `ActiveConnection` property.

This allows you to either `Set` your `ADODB.Connection` object or pass your connection string and let the `ADODB.Command` instantitate a new `ADODB.Connection` using that connection string.

Here are examples of using the two options

1. Use existing ADODB.Connection

   ```vb
   Dim cmd

   Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
   With cmd
     'Use existing object from include file to set connection.
     Set .ActiveConnection = YourConnObject
   End With
   ```

   > **IMPORTANT:** When using this method make sure the `YourConnObject` (`ADODB.Connection`) should have been opened using
   >
   > ```vb
   > 'Make sure connection has been opened.
   > Call YourConnObject.Open()
   > ```
   >
   > before assigning to the `ADODB.Command` object.
2. Use connection string variable (probably defined in your include) to set the connection that will be exclusively used by the `ADODB.Command` object.

   ```vb
   Dim cmd

   Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
   With cmd
     'Use connection string to instantiate a new connection to be used
     'exclusively by the ADODB.Command object.
     .ActiveConnection = YourConnectionString
   End With
   ```

   > **NOTE:** Unlike option 1 calling
   >
   > ```vb
   > 'Close ADODB.Command object
   > Call cmd.Close()
   > ```
   >
   > Will instantaneously destroy the ADODB.Connection (*that was assigned while setting the `ActiveConnection` property*).

---

**Useful Links**

- [Using Stored Procedure in Classical ASP .. execute and get results](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21944948/692942)

Comment: Hi, my main problem is when using SP on a Function / Sub as VBSCRIPT. a scenario would be, choosing a Name from dropdown then calling the Sub/Function to execute the SP and passing the Name argument. Now, I need to Call a New Conn.Open with since the #include was already processed before. I dont know how to elaborate this properly or maybe I am overthinking things. Right now, I put the connection string to a variable then reuse the connection string. The problem on this one, it shows the connection string on VIEW SOURCE.

Comment: @Sid When you say function you mean server-side not client-side right? Your going to have to show some code, I can't keep second guessing you, [post it in your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25392225/edit).

Comment: @Sid I'd recommend you post both the code for the page and the code for the include or people are going to struggle to help. We have no idea what `dataconnections.asp` does and as you mention it in [your comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25392225/asp-classic-getting-and-setting-the-conn-to-another-conn-object#comment39635562_25401753), it's important for us to know what it does.