# VBScript - Return a Recordset in an Array (SQL Like function)

Tags: arrays, vbscript, ado, sql-like, recordset

I have to write a program for my company's accountant, and I have a problem in returning articles' families in an array, all of the families I want to have have an Accounting code who begins with "707". Here's my code in VBScript :

```
Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
objConnection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\BASES\Base.mdb;Persist Security Info=False"
rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient

FamilleQuery = "Select Code from FamilleArticle Where CptVenteFrance Like '707%'"
rs.Open FamilleQuery, objConnection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic

'rs.MoveFirst
'Do
    'ListeFamille(rs.AbsolutePosition) = rs("Code")
    'rs.MoveNext
'Loop until rs.EOF

'ListeFamilleString = rs.GetString(AdClipString, -1,"/","/"," ")
'ListeFamille = split(ListeFamilleString,"/")

'Set ListeFamille = rs.GetRows

'for i=0 to ubound(rs)
    'ListeFamille(i) = rs.Fields("Code").Value(i)
'next

rs.Close
objConnection.Close
```

As comments you have all of my attempts to return the resultat of the recordset in an array and no one didn't work. 
Can someone say where I'm wrong please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try

```vb
Option Explicit

'ADO Constants
Const adCmdText = 1
Const adParamInput = 1
Const adVarWChar = 202

'Would usually be passed in from somewhere
Dim value: value = "707%"

Dim cmd, rs, data
Dim conn: conn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\BASES\Base.mdb;Persist Security Info=False"
Dim sql: sql = "Select Code from FamilleArticle Where CptVenteFrance Like ?"

Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
With cmd
  .ActiveConnection = conn
  .CommandType = adCmdText
  .CommandText = sql
  Call .Parameters.Append(.CreateParameter("@value", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 50))      

  Set rs = .Execute(, Array(value))
  If Not rs.EOF Then data = rs.GetRows()
  Call rs.Close()
  Set rs = Nothing
End With
Set cmd = Nothing

Dim row, rows

If IsArray(data) Then
  'Test data (2d Array, 0 = column, 1 = row)
  Call WScript.Echo(data(0, 0))

  'Retrieving all rows
  rows = UBound(data, 2)
  For row = 0 To rows
    'First column from each row.
    Call WScript.Echo(data(0, row))
  Next
Else
  'No records returned
End If
```

---

#### Useful Links

- [Using Stored Procedure in Classical ASP .. execute and get results](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21944948/692942) *(talk about returning data as an Array you can traverse)*

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `Set` in vbScript to set the array to the recordSet's rows.  You only use a `Set` where setting an object reference, which isn't the case here.

`ListeFamille = rs.GetRows` will set `ListeFamille` to a 2 dimensional array with the results of the recordset in it.

Here's an excerpt from one of my own function libraries:

```
oConnection.open sConnectionString
oRecordSet.open sSql, oConnection
If oRecordSet.RecordCount = 0 Then
    DataArray = ""
Else
    oRecordSet.MoveFirst
    DataArray = oRecordSet.GetRows
End If
```

Comment: I tried with and without `Set` and it didn't work, and I tried to read the array as a 1 dimmensional and 2 dimmensional array and none of them didn't work for me.

Comment: It will only work if the recordset returned is not empty - have you checked that there is data being returned from the query?

Comment: Yes, the recordset returns me the families without problem. `MsgBox rs(0)` returns the first family of my table but `MsgBox ListeFamille(0,0)` doesn't return anything (neither do `MsgBox ListeFamille(0)`).

Comment: I've added an extract from one of my own vbs function libraries that works - You should be getting the first family in ListeFamille(0,0) with this (and all the others, by incrementing the second dimension of the array - the first is for the various columns, of which you only have one in your query)

Comment: Returning an empty string for a query with no results seems wrong to me. I would recommend returning an empty array (`DataArray = Array`), or at least `Null`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I usually return an empty `Array` as well, also `RecordCount` isn't reliable depending on the `CursorType` and `CursorLocation`.

Comment: @Lankymart the cursortype and location are set earlier in the function, which returns `False` if the array isn't an array a little further down in the code - this isn't the whole function, just a cropped out bit. Coding standards here expect us to progress based on function return values rather than anything else

Comment: I wasn't getting at that. I was just pointing out that relying on `RecordCount` is not something I wouldn't recommend, because of how it behaves depending on how the `CursorType` and `CursorLocation` are set.