# How do you get number of columns from GetRows()?

Tags: sql, vbscript, asp-classic, ado

How just take an array of SQL? I never can see row with "noOfColumns3".
SQL is working.

```vb
Function getSubmittalNotes(submitId)
    Dim note_list, note_conn
    Dim test
    Set note_conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    note_conn.Open Application("DSN")
    Set note_list = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    note_list.CursorLocation = 3
    note_list.Open "SELECT [ID], [SubmitID], [UserID], [EnteredTime], [Note] FROM [dbo].[SubmittalNotesHistory] where [SubmitID] = " & submitId, note_conn, 1, 3
    'set notes = note_list.GetRows
    If note_list.RecordCount = 0 Then
        test = ""
        Response.Write "noOfColumns123 : <BR>"
    Else
        note_list.MoveFirst
        test = note_list.GetRows
        Response.Write "noOfColumns3 : " & test & "<BR>"
    End If
    note_list.Close
    Set note_list = Nothing
    note_conn.Close
    Set note_conn = Nothing
    Response.Write "getSubmittalNotes : " & test & " <BR>"
    getSubmittalNotes = test
End Function
```

Comment: You should use [`.Execute` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/execute-method-ado-connection) to get the recordset from the connection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBScript - Return a Recordset in an Array (SQL Like function)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37614727/vbscript-return-a-recordset-in-an-array-sql-like-function)

Answer (score 0):

try changing

```
test = note_list.GetRows
Response.Write "noOfColumns3 : " & test & "<BR>"
```

to

```
test = note_list.GetRows
Response.Write "noOfColumns3 : " & UBound( test ) & "<BR>"
```

for more info on the UBound() function: https://www.w3schools.com/asp/func_ubound.asp

Comment: @Lankymart: have you actually *recently* visited the site you linked to? Because it says w3schools is fine these days.

Comment: @Lankymart I'm afraid Marha is correct. While w3schools isn't perfect and isn't written by gurus, the content it has these days is just fine, and has no real flaws. It's totally valid and legit linking to it.

Comment: @lankymart: before you go running your mouth about not using w3schools (which I see the comment has been deleted, presumably by you) why don't you actually read the content? if there's something wrong with it, state what it is. same with down voting my answer (to whomever did so, presumably you again), explain what's wrong with it.

Comment: `Ubound(test) + 1` for the number of columns, I think?