# Return a recordset stored locally through a function

Tags: function, vbscript, adodb, recordset, secure-crt

I have a functional script in VB6 that I need to migrate to VBScript. As part of the reorganization of the code, I decided I was interested in utilizing a function to return a record set. Want to dispose of the connection to the database so the transaction closes so writing the recordset to an in memory object made sense to me. Way to many iterations trying to determine exactly what is wrong in my syntax, i'm not sure which would be the most compelling.

```
Sub Main()
    clientRecordset(" Exec [dbo].[StoredProc] ")

End Sub

Private function clientRecordset(sqlQuery) 

    Const adOpenStatic = 3
    Const adLockOptimistic = 3
    Const adUseClient = 3
    
    Dim objConnection, objRecordset
    
    Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set objRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    Set clientRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    objConnection.Open _
    "{connection properties}"
    
    
    clientRecordset = objConnection.Execute(sqlQuery) ' Error: operation is not allowed when object is closed
    clientRecordset = objRecordset.Open sqlQuery, objConnection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic 'Error: Expected end of statement 
    objRecordset.close()
    objConnection.close()
    SET objRecordset = Nothing
    Set objConnection = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VBScript - Return a Recordset in an Array (SQL Like function)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37614727/vbscript-return-a-recordset-in-an-array-sql-like-function)

Answer (score 0):

I have used something like this in production for years. Once I retrieve the RecordSet I loop over it and concatenate it into a String using a Field delimiter (FDel) and a Row delimiter (RDel) and split them into an array as needed after.

```
objRecordSet.Open(Query, objConnection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic)
objRecordSet.MoveFirst
Dim LCount = 0
Dim RCount = objRecordSet.RecordCount
Dim FCount = objRecordSet.Fields.Count
Dim FDel = "|"
Dim RDel = "$"
Dim Rows = ""
Do Until LCount = RCount
    For i = 0 To (FCount - 1)
        Fields = ""
        Fields = objRecordSet.Fields.Item(i)
        Rows = Rows & Fields & FDel
        Next
        Rows = Rows & RDel
        objRecordSet.MoveNext
        LCount = LCount + 1
    Loop
    Output = Rows
```

Comment: Why would you do this when [`objRecordSet.GetRows()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/getrows-method-ado?view=sql-server-ver15) will do [exactly this for you already](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22305896/692942)?

Comment: @user692942  that is a good point, in my case I was using this function in another application where I needed the value to return a string. In most cases I think you are correct that `objRecordSet.GetRows()` may be a better option.

Comment: In which case you would use [`objRecordSet.GetString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/getstring-method-ado?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: @user692942 Yeah that should be the answer, all I can say is that Microsoft has really improved there documentation over the last 5 years!

Comment: Actually if anything their documentation has gotten worse. However those particular pearls of wisdom have been present in the MDAC 2.5 CHM file for about 20 years.

Comment: I must be in a slightly different coding environment VBScript1.0 in SecureCRT just isn't playing well with Moir's code & with GetRows. I'm not getting a recordset at the moment 

I know that -86 parens is the correct way to call in my env: 
objRecordset.Open sqlQuery, objConnection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic 

...and a separate function that populates a variable for the sql stored procedure is called the same way, I'm catching an error on the objRecordSet1.MoveFirst line now. SMH